# How to overcome the ALT key issue in blender?

Tags: blender

What is the standard solution to this?

Unfortunately Blender relies heavily on the "Alt key". I don't mind using the Super key instead. But some bindings are not easy to find at all in Blender.

Comment: What alt issue?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but it sounds like you are referring to this issue:  [Avoiding Alt+mouse conflict in Blender](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing_blender/linux.html?highlight=alt). If that is so, please let us know what part of their solution you need help with and which desktop you are using. Please edit any new info into your question.

Comment: I asked because I don't use blender...

Answer (score 0):

1st off, sorry for implying that everyone should be using Blender (edited out now - Thanks). It must have been my frustration talking.

Back to this now... according to [this very in depth thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?207215-Alt-key-doesn-t-work-in-Ubuntu-SOLVED&p=2115869&viewfull=1#post2115869) (and others I've found), the best and easiest solution is to use "CompizConfig Settings Manager". I found it in the Ubuntu Software Center.
I can't speak from 1st hand experience yet, but I'm half-way now.